# Windows created a new folder full of garbage on my USB Flash, how can I delete it without needing to format the entire partition?

Tags: windows-8, filesystems

I created a new folder inside my USB Flash partition with my Windows 8 machine:
[image]

It looks like everything was OK, but it spent more than the usual time to create it(like 1 or 2 min instead of 1 or 2 ms). When I opened it to put my files inside, I just came across a lot of random garbage (strange characters) inside the new folder (including additional folders and files):

[image]

Now, I just can't delete it by any means; by using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> inside Windows 8:

[image]

As you can see, it tells me that the paths and the filenames are too long to delete it.

Or using my Linux Ubuntu machine(by using 'rm -rf'), it also **returned me that the paths and filenames are too long**..

**So, how can I delete this undesired folder from my Flash USB without needing to format the entire partition?**

Comment: Have you tried renaming the files? It seems that you are [not alone](https://www.google.com/search?q=new+folder+strange+characters&%7Bgoogle:searchFieldtrialParameter%7Dsourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). See if someone got it to work. Edit: [this guy](http://www.techyv.com/questions/strange-folder-and-file-names) seem to have fixed it.

Comment: How strange... I wonder what caused this...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would assume that your file system itself is defective. This would make it unlikely that you could simply interact with it and delete the problematic entry.

Instead, you may want to run `chkdsk` on the disk in question to try to fix the invalid entries. Be sure to provide the `/F` parameter to attempt to fix broken entries:

```
chkdsk G: /F
```

Comment: Problem solved, just used chkdsk /F on it, then the undesired folder became a file, that I could normally delete by using shift+del on Windows. Thank you so much.